# Indesign text frame properties not applying to text

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I been setting up multiple text frames in Indesign, copying text from another file into the new one. The thing is that the text I copy does not get updated to the text frame properties. How can I solve this without having to retype everything again?

Comment: What do you mean by "updated to the text frame properties"? Do you mean the type retains its original formatting and doesn't respect the formatting of type in the new text frame?

Comment: Exactly that, how can I make the text use the format of the text frame its on?

Answer (score 1):

If you copy and paste between InDesign or InCopy and Indesing paste without formatting SHIFT+CTR+V. That should force text to inherit style you pasting it into.

Comment: Shift-Command-V for us Mac users. ;)